# Exception while getting the LWC bundle for reference @Salesforce/schema/Account.Name

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am creating a lightning-record-form component to display records from Account Object:
This is the js file:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import Account_Name from '@Salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import Account_Type from '@Salesforce/schema/Account.Type';
import Account_Industry from '@Salesforce/schema/Account.Industry';

export default class AccountCreateSampleComp extends LightningElement {
    objectApiName='Account';
    fieldList=[Account_Name,Account_Type,Account_Industry];
    handleAccountCreate(event){
    }
}
```

This is the template/html file:

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-form object-api-name={objectApiName} fields={fieldList} onsuccess={handleAccountCreate}></lightning-record-form>
</template>
```

I have attached the screenshot of the message received when I try to deploy[image]

Comment: what is the exception message? Do you any screenshot? Can you add these details to the question?

Comment: @sanketkumar I have attached the snip of the msg received

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have written **S** capital in salesforce while importing the fields in your JS file.

What you have is:-

```
import NAME_FIELD from '@Salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
```

where as the correct import statement is :-

```
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @paritoshparimal please upvote this answer and mark it as the best answer in order to reward sanket for his effort in helping you out.